# Windows 10 - Different methods to disable driver signature check and their realations

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, digital-signature, data-integrity

**For Windows 10**

I am examining different methods to monitor the disabling of "driver signature check". From a search online I found 3 main method:

1. from administrator cmd run:

   ```
   bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
   bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
   ```

   actually, `bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS`  didn't show an error (?)
2. from GPedit tool:

   > User -> Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Driver Installation -> Code signing for drivers

   Click on "**Disabled**", then on "OK".
3. set registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Driver Signing`
   ```

   with `BehaviorOnFailedVerify` key value to "".
   (Actually, this key is not present on my machine (Windows 10))

---

I am trying to find the relations between them, and find a way to monitor the disabling of this checking. When I run method (1), there is no effect on method (2) and vice versa. Also, when either method (1) or (2) are called the registry key in method (3) is not created.

Usually, Windows manages configurations via registry keys, but in this case I couldn't find any relevant key created/changed when the methods are called, is there such a registry key?

From a monitoring point of view, how can I know that the driver signature check was disabled?

Comment: Is there a specific issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @music2myear yes, I approach this problem from a monitoring point of view, I wish to monitor such modifications

Comment: In what sort of environment? Is this on a single computer? A domain of computers? What is the practical situation you are trying to observe, or prevent? You really need to add more information to your question.

Comment: @music2myear for the completeness of the question, it would be great to monitor the disabling of signature check for a single computer both in the case of user actually working on it and the case of someone connecting to it with ssh.

Comment: Please use the EDIT button below your question to add this and any other relevant and necessary information to the question itself so that people do not need to read through the comments to learn this context.